# Exclude pages from WordPress menu builder

Tags: wordpress

do you know how I can exclude certain pages from the WordPress menu creator without using any plugin? With actions or filters?

In other words, I don't want certain pages to be added to, so I want to filter them so they don't appear.

Comment: I update my answer to also filter page on ajax search in menu editor take a look to hide_from_menu_page_selector function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean remove specific page from Appearance-> menu -> pages selector ?

You can use [pre_get_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) filter for that.

### Long answer

#### 1. Add custom field

First add a custom field on your page to define if it should be displayed or not in the page selector of the menu editor.

```php
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_hide_in_menu_editor_field' );
function add_hide_in_menu_editor_field() {
   add_meta_box('hide_in_menu_selector','Page menu option', 'hide_in_menu_editor_callback', 'page', 'normal', 'high');
}
function hide_in_menu_editor_callback( $post ) {
   global $post;
   $isHidden=get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'hide_in_menu_selector', true );
    ?>
    <label>
       <input type="checkbox" name="hide_in_menu_selector" value="1" <?php echo ($isHidden ? 'checked="checked"': '');?>/> Hide in menu page selector ?
    </label>
    <?php
}

add_action('save_post', 'save_hide_in_menu_selector'); 
function save_hide_in_menu_selector($post_id){ 
   update_post_meta( $post_id, 'hide_in_menu_selector', $_POST['hide_in_menu_selector']==="1");
}
```

#### 2. Filter page selector query

```php
function hide_from_menu_page_selector($query) {
    global $pagenow;
    $isAdminMenuPage = is_admin() && $pagenow === 'nav-menus.php';
    $isAjaxSearchMenu = ($pagenow ==='admin-ajax.php' && $_POST['action'] === 'menu-quick-search');
    if (($isAdminMenuPage || $isAjaxSearchMenu) && $query->get('post_type') === 'page') {
        $query->set( 'meta_query', 
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'     => 'hide_in_menu_selector',
                'value'   => false,
                'compare' => '='
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'hide_in_menu_selector',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
            )
        ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'hide_from_menu_page_selector' );
```

### Short answer (Bad practice)

Here is an example to hide pages with a particular id (Just for example, but it's not good practice).

Change $page_ids_to_exclude value with your target id

```php
function hide_specific_ids_from_menu_page_selector($query) {
    // Get current admin page
    global $pagenow;
    $page_ids_to_exclude = array(5, 10);

    // Check if we are on admin and if current page is menu editor
    if ( is_admin() && $pagenow === 'nav-menus.php') {
        if ($query->get('post_type') === 'page' ) {
            $query->set( 'post__not_in', $page_ids_to_exclude );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'hide_specific_ids_from_menu_page_selector' );
```

**Note: It is not a good practice to apply filters on particular ids because these will be different depending on the environment.**